# Managing dependency of one VS extension on another

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget, vsix

I've written a VS2012 extension for internal use that simplifies the process of publishing and updating any nuget packages from the nuspecs that are contained within the currently loaded solution.

I've referenced Nuget.Core from the official package source to do this, have added an extension level dependency on the official nuget extension, and then marked my local reference to the Nuget.Core assembly *not* to be included in the VSIX.

This was all fine until yesterday, when nuget was updated - now my extension does not work at all as it cannot load the older version of this core assembly (the version number is always changed).

I've just tried getting the new version from nuget, but it's not been released yet.

So I'm faced with a couple of options:

- Release the extension again, with a binding redirect to the newer version
- Reference the DLL from the installed location of the nuget extension

But neither of these seems ideal as I don't want to have to keep rebuilding and releasing my package whenever nuget is also updated! Equally I don't want to deploy my copy of the assembly with the extension, as it could stop the main nuget extension working.

Anybody got any other options for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I tweeted this question to Luan Nguyen](https://twitter.com/RealLordZoltan/status/304616284446916610) - who works all over the Nuget product.

As you'll see from the response chain there, the solution is **not** to reference Nuget.Core directly, because it's not supported.  There are Service providers offered by Nuget for doing some of the Nuget operations, but not the stuff I was looking for.

So, I've ended up following his suggestion - grabbing the Nuget sources off codeplex and building a local copy of the assembly (with a different identity so it doesn't interfere with the nugget extension).

I have to then keep this updated if new package features are added to Nuget, but it will carry on working if the extension is updated.

The other option was to ILMerge the local Nuget.Core into the extension; however it's a WPF assembly and they can't be merged.  I could have created a standard satellite assembly into which I could then merge Nuget.Core I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

As you extension really depends on Nuget I guess the best choice to release a new version of your extension every time.

Regarding VS extensibility itself, as far as I know, there is a way to communicate between extensions using ServiceProvider. You could either share your service, or get shared ones. So if Nuget provides any services you could try to use it via them.

Please check the documentation for the [ServiceProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.framework.serviceprovider.aspx) as a strating point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distribute your software with the precise versions of its dependencies that you developed it against. The user can't be expected to have them.

Afaik, this is the norm. Why would it break anything? Try it.

Comment: The issue here is when the other extension is updated, thus deploying a newer version of the DLL on which my code depends (crucially, with a different assembly version).  This then breaks my extension because it was built against a lower version - throwing a .Net runtime load error.  I can't restrict my team not to update Nuget whenever it comes out. - but equally I can't distribute the core DLL because it will break the Nuget extension when they update it.

Comment: Can't the computer hold multiple versions of any library simultaneously? You can then explicitly reference the precise version you need.